# Can you use the verb pour with solid substances, like "pour flour"?

Tags: verbs

Can I use verb POUR in a sentence for solid substance eg: flour, sugar and salt etc?

Comment: Yes, you can pour any _flowing_ substance.  Cambridge Dictionary gives as one of its examples _Pour the sugar into the bowl_.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the verb "pour" in a sentence for solid substances like flour, sugar, and salt. Here are a few examples:

> 1. "Please pour the flour into the mixing bowl."
> 2. "She poured the sugar into the container."
> 3. "Carefully pour the salt into the recipe."
> 4. "He poured a cup of flour into the measuring cup."
> 5. "The chef poured the sugar into the saucepan."

Remember, although the verb "pour" is commonly used for liquids, it can also be used when transferring or adding solid substances in a flowing or smooth manner.

Comment: Just FYI, [AI generated content must be marked as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393682/273494).

Comment: @ColleenV Out of curiosity, what is leading you to believe that this answer contains AI generated content?

Comment: @FriendlyRacoon Because it reads like it was written by an LLM, not by a human. Compare it to Kate's comment.

Comment: @ColleenV Just because it looks like an AI generated answer, It doesn't mean It is.

Comment: @KavehBehnia Sure, but I read your other posts and I'm pretty sure this is not entirely your own work so I thought I would make you aware of the site's policy on properly referencing text you didn't write.

Comment: That said, if I'm wrong and you're just emulating LLM output because you believe it is well-written English, you shouldn't do that. It's grammatical, but it's not great writing unless you customize the model to have a more human voice.

Comment: @ColleenV That's even worse. Customizing AI generated answer doesn't work here.

Comment: @ColleenV I find the sample sentences idiomatic. //Are flour, sugar and salt solid substances? :)

Comment: @KavehBehnia You misunderstood me. I'm talking about training a LoRa to apply an effect to the base model.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, LLMs can generate idiomatic single sentences quite well. It's actually a good use of genAI to ask it to generate an example usage of a phrase or word and would be undetectable as AI generated.

Comment: @ColleenV Why do you say: You shouldn't do that? If a person does that and we can't really tell, what difference does it make?

Comment: @Lambie There's a difference between using a tool to generate some examples for your answer, and using a tool to generate the entire answer. Every sentence can be idiomatic on its own and be a verbose incoherent mess when jammed together.

Comment: @Lambie There are multiple reasons why, to me, it makes a difference. First, if someone posts something they got from an LLM, that isn't their own work, and it should be properly attributed to the source (this is also a Stack Exchange Policy). Also, reputation here is supposed to represent what the community feels about a user's expertise in an area, not in their ability to use ChatGPT (et. al.).  If someone wanted a ChatGPT answer, they probably would have asked ChatGPT -- They come here for the human *experience* that ChatGPT's amalgamation of "knowledge" just can't have.

Comment: Not saying that this answer is or is not AI-assisted, but yeah, don't do that ...

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds That's the point

Comment: Pouring a cup of flour into a measuring cup is a bad example!